# How do you wait for a DOM element to exist be before being able to manipulate it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm using Angular material and md-select in my AngularJS application.When a user click on the md-select a dropdown list appears and an overlay is added to the DOM with the tag Name .
I'm trying to add a class or a style as soon the user clicked on the md-select

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("md-backdrop");
el.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";
```

So because I'm assuming he doesn't exist in the DOM yet when the code run I've got TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined in my console.

Is there any way I can wait for the tag to exist before adding the style or is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Why you just don't add a style? .md-backdrop { background-color: rgba(...) }

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to affect DOM elements directly if you are using the AngularJS framework.  You should be using the API that AngularJS provides you.  Please show the markup with the `md-select` and `md-backdrop`.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil I want to add the style only if the user is on a mobile device, so I've used javascript to detect that and then I want to add the style if necessary

Comment: @G.Tranter when the md-select hasn't been triggered then the HTMLCollection for the tag md-backdrop is an Empty array

Comment: @RomainGaget - then fix your code sample so that it is correct.

Comment: @zero298 the following tag is added at the top inside the body <md-backdrop class="md-select-backdrop md-click-catcher ng-scope" style="position: fixed;"></md-backdrop>

Comment: ok I understand. But you can apply a class name to a root element depending if you are on a mobile device or not, and define a specific style for md-backdrop :  .is-mobile .md-backdrop { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately theres no way to watch the UI in pure vanilla JS if you're pushing elements to the DOM after render time.

If whats above is static HTML you can use the event that is fired when the DOM is rendered

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("md-backdrop");
  el.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";
});
```

Comment: This idea is fine but the code won't work properly because it is a copy of the OP's original code sample and has an error. The `getElementsByTagName()` function returns an `HTMLCollection` object not an actual `HTMLElement`. So it does not have a 'style' property. See API. Try `el.item(0).style` instead.